# How to redirect to 404 use NotFoundHttpException on Handle.php laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i want to redirect all 404 error to home page with handle.php , i use laravel 8 please help me.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
          
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return redirect back to the home page :

```
$this->renderable(function(NotFoundHttpException $ex, $request) {
    return redirect('/');
})
```

but it will produce a `302` status code instead of `404` but if you want to produce a `404` but still show the homepage.

```
$this->renderable(function(NotFoundHttpException $ex, $request) {
    return response()->view('homepage', [], 404);
})
```

[Error Handling - Rendering Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#rendering-exceptions)

Comment: after using your code and creating a home.blade.php file it redirected. Thank you very much.

Comment: "if you want to produce a 404" Status code can be used in redirect function as second argument.

Comment: No it will produce an error ! `InvalidArgumentException` since `404` is not a redirect status code